# How many different variations of this command?

Tags: syntax

That's an unusual question. Let's say I have one command with this synopsis:

```
/usr/bin/wc [-c | -m | -C]
```

and second command with

```
head [-number | -n number] [filename]
```

The question is how many different usage variations(combinations) of these commands can I get? And what are they?

I'm new to UNIX and I'm trying to understand command syntax in general. This question is a part of my "homework" and I'm confused. A friend of mine told me that the answer of a second (head) command is 6. So there should be 6 variations and my guess is that they are

```
head 
head -number
head -n number
head filename
head -number filename
head -n number filename
```

Is this correct? If so, does a " | " sign between -number and -n number means "or" so that both of them should not be used together? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

`[-a|-b]` means "either `-a` or `-b`, but not both, and both are optional".

`[-a][-b]` would mean "both `-a` and `-b` may occur, but both are optional".

`-a b` would mean "`-a` is a required option with a required option-argument `b`".

The standard `wc` utility looks like

```
wc [-c|-m] [-lw] [file...]
```

`-c` and `-m` are mutually exclusive, but both are optional. `-l` can be used with `-w` (and/or with one of `-c` or `-m`), but these are also optional. There may be zero or many additional files.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's very helpful. So the "wc" command has 4 variations?

Comment: @Deividas The command at the top of the question? Yes. Standard `wc` looks like `wc [-c|-m] [-lw] [file...]`.

Comment: Yes I was asking about my example, I know that it is not a standard command. Thanks!